# How to replace JSON data in database?

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite

The below JSON data is one of the field "JsonData" in the table "Profiles". In the below JSON data, I need to replace the value "Name" to "Other name" use sqlite in python

```
{"Id":"jwefwawlct6hlb6vs2ekotettc1dxvfv00d238jmbupfr1fnrz","Name":"CarlRisinger20409@outlook.com,"SaveType":1,"IdOnClould":"j0ZyVflWPD"}
```

I have executed `SELECT JSON_REPLACE(JsonData, "$.Name", "Other name") FROM "Profiles" WHERE name = "CarlRisinger20409@outlook.com"` in SQLITE

It showed `{"Id":"jwefwawlct6hlb6vs2ekotettc1dxvfv00d238jmbupfr1fnrz","Name":"Other name","SaveType":1,"IdOnClould":"j0ZyVflWPD"}` but it can't save on database.

Please know me any method to replace JSON values in the database with python. Thank you.

Comment: You executed a `SELECT` query. Why would that replace anything in the database? Please show the code where you [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) your database. (I closed as _needs more details_, but the other two votes were "opinion based", so that's what it shows)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you do it in python and you did not show the code, I suggest you checking if you commit the changes.

```
con.commit()
```

[check out the sample code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#tutorial)

Comment: While this might answer the question, the recommended action for ambiguous questions is to leave a comment asking for clarification. Since you do not yet have the [reputation required to leave a comment](/help/privileges), you should contribute to other well-asked questions that do not require clarification. Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!